# Chrome continue download when OS X sleeps

Tags: mac, google-chrome, download, sleep

Will Google Chrome continue downloading even when my Mac goes to sleep?

**EDIT:**
By sleep, I mean the timeouts I set in Energy Saver Preferences from the battery icon. For example, I set Computer Sleep in 1 minute, and Display Sleep in 1 minute, what happens to my ongoing download in Chrome?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean: when it awakes from sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer is asleep, none of the components are working, for example your hard drive, so there is no place to store information.

So, I can't see how it could work.

Comment: One thing to note is that OS X is typically pretty good at staying awake when it's still doing stuff. Hopefully Chrome is smart enough to let OS X know that it's not ready for bed yet.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, No, it won't.